# Is $|(1 - k\epsilon)(2 - k\epsilon)...(n - k\epsilon)| \leq n!$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, factorial

Let $\epsilon \in \mathbb{R}$, $0 \le \epsilon \le 1$. Let $n$ be a positive integer. Let $k$ be a non-negative integer, $0 \leq k \leq n+1$.

Is it true that $|(1 - k\epsilon)(2 - k\epsilon)...(n - k\epsilon)| \leq n!$

I tried some numbers and it seems to work but I am not sure if it's true in general. Any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: What happens as $\epsilon$ gets close to $1$ and $i$ gets large?

Comment: I read $i$ as an imaginary number. It isn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have $0 \le k\epsilon < n+1$.

For $k \epsilon \ge 1$, we take $m = \lfloor k \epsilon \rfloor$. For $0 \le k \epsilon < 1$, we take $m = 1$.

Either way we have $|m - k \epsilon| \le 1$ for some $1 \le m \le n$.

Now we have:
$$|1-k\epsilon|\le |m-k\epsilon| + |1-m| \le m$$
$$:$$
$$|(m-2)- k\epsilon| \le |m- k\epsilon|+|-2| \le 3$$
$$|(m-1)- k\epsilon| \le |m- k\epsilon|+|-1| \le 2$$
$$|m- k\epsilon| \le 1$$
$$|(m+1)- k\epsilon| \le |m- k\epsilon|+|1| \le 2\le m+1$$
$$|(m+2)- k\epsilon| \le |m- k\epsilon|+|2| \le 3 \le m+2$$
$$:$$
$$|n - k\epsilon| \le |m-k\epsilon| + |n-m| \le n-m+1\le n$$

Hence we see that $|(1-k\epsilon)(2-k\epsilon)\dots(n-k\epsilon)| \le m!(n-m+1)! \le n!$ by term-by-term comparison.

Comment: Note: the $m!(n-m+1)!$ is inferred from the second to last column, while $n!$ is inferred from the rightmost column.

Comment: Note: regarding the strict inequality in the first line ($k \epsilon < n + 1$), it is actually possible that we have equality, i.e. $k \epsilon = n + 1$, but this only happens when $\epsilon = 1$ and $k = n + 1$, in which case $|(1 - k\epsilon)(2 - k\epsilon)...(n - k\epsilon)| = |(1 - (n + 1))(2 - (n + 1))...(n - (n + 1))|$ $= |((n + 1) - 1)((n + 1) - 2)...((n + 1) - n)| = |n(n-1)...1| = n! \leq n!$. So it's true in this case too.

Comment: @twosigma: I see that another user has changed your question quite significantly. Hopefully it did not contradict your original intent much.

Comment: No worries, your solution answers the original question, and with that easy modification it also answers the current question. So all is good.

Answer (score 0):

Let's replace $n+1$ by $n$ and $k\epsilon$ by $x$. Then the question is:

> For an integer $n>1$, and $x\in\mathbb{R}$, let $f_n(x)=\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}|k-x|$.
> Show that $f_n(x)\leqslant f_n(0)$ for $0\leqslant x\leqslant n$.

We may assume that $x$ is not an integer. Since $f_n(x)=f_n(n-x)$, we may also assume that $x\leqslant n/2$. Now, if $x>1$ then $f_n(x)/f_n(x-1)=(x-1)/(n-x)<x/(n-x)\leqslant 1$. Thus, by induction (i.e. after repeated decrease of $x$ by $1$), we may assume that $0<x<1$. Finally, $f_n(x)$ is clearly decreasing on this interval, and we're done.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the integer lattice consisting of the points $1,\dots,n$. We shift this through the reals until the point $1$ is on the point $-n$.

Each point in the lattice that is positive is less than or equal to the nearest integer above or equal to it.

Each point in the lattice that is negative, add $n$ to it. Then they are less than or equal to the remaining integers from the original lattice.